# How to restore desktop workarea after SPI_SETWORKAREA

Tags: winapi

I have a program that modifies desktop workarea using SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA,...)

It restores original area on exit, but if I kill the program, it won't restore original area and no programs will maximalize. I can restore original area by logging off from windows.

Is there any way how to restore workarea programatically on program start?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? You could save the work area to a configuration file or the Windows registry and restore it on program start.

Comment: @zett42 And that's an answer. I was soo focused on how to calculate correct workarea that I missed such simple solution.